# MATLAB: How to NOT export data outside plot axis to SVG

Tags: matlab, svg, plot, export, inkscape

Probably a too special question, but just in case someone has faced a similar problem.

I am using plot2svg to get plots from Matlab to Inkscape. It works fine, except for one pretty annoying problem. If I want to show just a zoomed part of a curve, plot2svg "captures" the whole curve and then clips it. As a result, the SVG file is much larger than it could be, and sometimes Inkscape even crashes on complex curves.

What would help is some way to remove the data outside the axis before exporting SVG. I've tried brushing (remove unbrushed), but then plot2svg fails:

```
Attempted to access parts(1); index out of bounds because numel(parts)=0.

Error in plot2svg>line2svg (line 2237)
    if parts(1)~=1

Error in plot2svg>axchild2svg (line 1365)
    line2svg(fid,groupax,axpos,x,y,scolorname,linestyle,linewidth)

Error in plot2svg>axes2svg (line 1042)
group = axchild2svg(fid,id,axIdString,ax,group,paperpos,axchild,axpos,groupax,projection,boundingBoxAxes);

Error in plot2svg (line 221)
    group=axes2svg(fid,id,ax(j),group,paperpos);
```

Can anyone suggest any solution? I would like to avoid using the EPS or PDF export in Matlab because their quality is much worse than that of the plot2svg.

Matlab 2011b 64bit, plot2svg 10-Nov-2010, Win 7 Pro 64.

Comment: If you have a crashy document, and it is valid SVG, would you submit it to the Inkscape team? I think they would welcome any opportunities to improve their loading resilience.

Comment: I have already done it a while ago: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/888559. Unfortunately, it is still not fixed. Besides, I am using Inkscape's ability to export drawings as PDF+TeX. This export takes huge time for large polylines.

Comment: Ah thanks, well you've done your bit! `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All values of your curve that lie outside the (zoomed in) axes should be set to NaN. Matlab will not draw these points and, hence, plot2svg will not export them. However, this involves redrawing the curve after zooming.

Make sure to save a handle to your curve when plotting it:

```
figure(1)  
h = plot(yourXdata, yourYdata);
```

Then zoom in on your area of interest and afterwards run the following code:

```
figure(1)
hold on  
myXlim = xlim;  
myYlim = ylim;  

% crop your data  
yourXdata(yourXdata < myXlim(1)) = NaN;  
yourXdata(yourXdata > myXlim(2)) = NaN;  

yourYdata(yourYdata < myYlim(1)) = NaN;  
yourYdata(yourYdata > myYlim(2)) = NaN;  

% delete old curve and draw the new one  
delete(h);
plot(yourXdata, yourYdata);
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe it's the best option until the bug in plot2svg is corrected. One suggestion however. The above described algorithm removes all data points outside the visible region. You should  keep one point outside in each direction, for the curves to reach the borders. In the meantime I've done more or less the same thing as a workaround: since my data is plotted in a separate function (it's many curves, not just one), I just pass the region of interest to it, and it plots only stuff which will be visible.